# How/why was this question deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/61330/does-searching-a-keyword-on-google-make-the-crawlers-look-harder-in-the-future (only available to Moderators and 10k+ users)

It was migrated here from Super User. It was probably well on its way to being closed (it's practically unanswerable) but only had two votes so far.

It was deleted by Community yesterday, but I don't know why. It doesn't, to me, meet the criteria for auto-deletion.

It had a score of -2 and was originally asked on June 5. However, it wasn't yet closed. I suppose the "low view count" could come into play, but shouldn't the counter be reset when it was migrated? It was deleted a mere 15 hours after it was migrated.

Don't get me wrong; I'm not looking to get the question back. I'm just trying to grok the deletion algorithm and see if there might be an issue for migrated questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It met the auto-delete criteria:

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/133693

> Just to formally document the exact policies we have in place to
>   remove old abandoned / dead questions, [the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) will
>   delete questions in the following circumstances:
>
> **If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> **...or...**
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> **If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0 *or* a score of 1 with a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has a viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> These checks are run every week across all sites.

Comment: I would have thought that being migrated would reset the clock, but I guess not. And I suppose it didn't get to -2 until it got migrated here, so that's why it wasn't already gone on SU.